# RabbitMQ Multiple Consumers with Single connection Object

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 35 queues in my application. I have created a single connection object and 35 unique channel to consume the data from the dedicated queue.

Some time (after running 6 hrs and 12 hrs), I'm not able to receive any messages from the RabbitMQ. In the rabbitMQ management portal the consumers are not available.

Exception in the RabbitMQ loggers:

> closing AMQP connection <0.10985.3> (127.0.0.1:63478 ->
>   127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'): client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

Is this fine with one connection for the all the consumers? Or is something wrong?

I am using RabbitMQ 3.6.12 and amqp-client-5.5.0.jar for the Java client.

Comment: Did your Java application throw an exception or otherwise crash?

Comment: Single connection for application level is fine. Try to check event viewer or some system level logging just in case if firewall or something closing the connection.